# Does there exist a higher-dimensional 5-sided "tetrahedron + 1"?

Tags: general-topology, polyhedra, natural-numbers, polytopes, simplicial-stuff

The first shape is "0"-sided and is a point.  The next shape is a line segment and it's "1"-sided.  The next shape is a triangle and it's 3-sided.  The next shape is a tetrahedron and it's 4-sided.  Can we define some higher-dimensional 5-sided regular shape which is the next shape in this sequence?

You can reach the next shape by placing a point equidistant to all previous points in the next higher dimension.

Comment: In general, this is called a ["simplex" or "$n$-simplex"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex).

Comment: @Blue thanks.  I will read that

Comment: In particular, see [5-cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/5-cell). Here the 5 "sides" are tetrahedra, just like the 4 sides of a tetrahedron are triangles, the 3 sides of a triangle are line segments, and the 2 "sides" (or rather, ends) of a line segment are points.

Comment: The 4D 24-cell though not a simplex, shares simplex-like features, being a regular polytope which is self dual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplex is the easiest polytope, existing within all dimensions. It is nothing but the pyramid on a simplicial base (of one dimension less). In fact, take any simplex, attach to every facet a copy of that simplex again, and fold those copies up into the next dimension, then those will all meet at a single point atop the central simplex, which then will become its base.

This very construction already shows by induction, that the D-dimensional simplex would have D+1 facets, which all are D-1 dimensional simplices. Thus I can be affirmative, the 4th dimensional simplex is a pentachoron, i.e. it is built from 5 cells, all being tetrahedra.

In fact, the element count of all subelements of any dimension would be given by the numbers of the Pascal triangle: eg. a triangle has 3 vertices and 3 sides; a tetrahedron has 4 vertices, 6 edges, and 4 faces; a pentachoron has 5 vertices, 10 edges, 10 triangles, and 5 tetrahedra; etc.

The constructive device given above surely requires that the circumradius of the lower dimensional simplex is less than one edge unit, in order to allow to build an unit-edged pyramid on top. Again by induction, using right that very construction of a D-dimensional simplex, you could derive that crucial circumradius formula being 
$$r=\sqrt{\frac{D}{2(D+1)}},$$
thus prooving its existance for every dimension.

--- rk